# Connect to vmware guest when there is no internet connection

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

I had set up virtual machine with  debian 7 guest on my windows 7 laptop and was using it for developing a website. Now I do not have internet connection on my laptop. Is it possible in a same way connect to the guest as usual by ftp and remote mysql?

When I had internet doing `ifconfig` in guest, showed me the ip of it smth like `192.168.0.107`, which I used to connect to guest from host. Now the some command does not show any ip, instead it shows `UP BROADCAST MULTICAST`

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Host side

Add another network in [`Virtual Network Editor`], a custom **`VMnet4`**, having static **`NETWORK_ADDRESS`** `192.168.78.0/24`

Check option to [Connect host virtual network adapter to this network] to **ON**

Check option to [Use local DHCP ... ] to be **OFF** ( prefer static-IP addresses here )

---

### Guest side

Add another **`VirtualNIC`**, attached to **`VMnet4`**, with static **`IP_ADDRESS`** `192.168.78.100`

---

### Once done,

your Dev/Test-LAB will work inside this sand-box-ed environment, be the laptop connected to an external world or not.

Comment: man I have got another situation, maybe u would know the solution thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348536/vmware-set-guest-static-ip-address-with-host-connected-to-private-network-by-3g