# Vmware set guest static ip address with host connected to private network by 3G modem

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have windows 7 host and guest debian 7 on vmware. I am connected to internet by 3G modem and this is the ip config of host

```
PPP adapter [provider name]:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.47.235.94
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
```

what I am trying to achieve is to

```
1) set static ip for guest
2) connect from host to guest by ftp and remote mysql
3) access internet in guest
```

In the past I had cable internet connection and the ipconfig of host was this

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

that time I just changed the network type in vmware as bridged and had this

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

in `etc/resolv.conf` and also these lines in `etc/network/interfaces` and all things were just fine.

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.107
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

---

I tried to do a similar thing

```
address 10.47.235.95  # just putting some ip other than the host's ip
netmask 255.255.255.255 # same as for host
network 192.168.1.0     # did not know what to put, so just left the same
gateway 0.0.0.0 # host's gateway
```

but does not work, neither I can connect to guest, nor I have internet in guest.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that your subnet mask is 255.255.255.255. With this subnet mask you can't add even a single guest to your network (theoretically if S.N mask is 255.255.255.255, there is no network). It should be at least 255.255.255.252. When you give the IP 10.47.235.95 to your guest, it won't be connected with your network because this IP belongs to another network. If you select Bridged network type, your guest is directly connected with your network card and will try to use an IP. But since your S.N mask is 255.255.255.255 there is no IP available for your guest. Try to use NAT mode instead of bridged one. If this don't work than you have to change your modem S.N mask. When you had the S.N mask 255.255.255.0 it was OK because this network allows 253 guests to be connected with the modem.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I got the mask part. if I connect by NAT, I have internet in guest, but guest does not have ip, how can I connect to its localhost ? thanks

Comment: If you connect by NAT than your host will create a virtual network. Practically this is a LAN. You can add as many guests as you want (up to 253), and they can connect with each other and with host. Type /ipconfig in your host's DOS and you will see that he has 2 different IPs, because it's in the same time in 2 different networks (1. Internet 2. your local network, LAN). The first IP should be 10.47.235.94; the second one is an C class IP: 192.168.x.y. To access your host's server by a guest do as follows: Open your guest browser, and in the URL bar type your host's IP address (192.168.x.y).

Comment: yes, but how to access the guest from host, I need to access the localhost of the guest from host ? thanks

Comment: Guest has an IP too. You can access guest mysql's database by using this IP. Use its IP on your applications (what ever they are), and you will have access to your guest localhost. For example: if you have installed XAMPP or WAMP in guest, type its IP in URL of your host and you can access the localhost interface.

Comment: yeah, you were right, as im connected by NAT, the guest has an ip address, it is `192.168.252.138`, but trying to open in browser says `page is not available` and trying to ping gives `Request time out`. Btw, I can ping host from guest. and I have internet in guest, just can not connect to guest from host

Comment: I will post another question for this

Comment: Deactivate firewall in guest and try again. If your firewall is activated it won't ping.

Comment: I do not have have any firewall rules in the guest. Doing `/sbin/iptables -L` shows empty list. any ideas ? thanks

Comment: got the solution, the `VMware Network Adapter VMnet8` was disabled, as soon as I enabled it, I succeeded in pinging the guest with NAT connection. Lets add the summary of your comments with this info and accept the answer ? thank you for your efforts to help